# MySQL User Can't View, Edit or Debug Stored Procedures (Amazon RDS)

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-rds, dbforge

I had some issues about the creation of new users for my MySQL RDS. The process was the following:

```
CREATE USER 'james'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'AdminTest2022';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testdatabase.* TO 'james'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

So, connecting with the previous user and making some privileges testing I found most of them are ok but I found a problem when I tried to access to the stored procedures

[image: Access to SP Error]

When I checked the privileges of the user

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'james'@'%';
```

I got

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `james`@`%`
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testdatabase`.* TO `james`@`%` WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Why I can't view, edit or debug any SP if my user has all the privileges over it?

By the way

```
Engine version: 8.0.28
Tool: dbForge Studio 2020 for MySQL 9.0.597
```

Also from the beginning of my RDS creation I got

```
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1
```

I'm out of ideas, I'd appreciate any suggestion, I didn't find similar questions about this issue so far and that's why I'm asking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testdatabase`  permission do not give to see the procedure or function code in the database.  (I know it sucks!)

You can do
Grant show_routine on testdatabase.* to user@% ;
then the user can see the code for ALL proc/function even out of the database. it's a SERVER scope privilege.
please refer to this
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_show-routine
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-procedure-code.html